# function returns before await has resolved promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

when I call `UserService.signUp()` from `index.js` then my var `x` is undefined. apparently my function `singUp()` returns back to my `router.post` function after `await hash()`. how can I fix this issue? I would like for the `signUp` function to wait for the `hash` function to complete, before the function returns.

index.js:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    var username = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password,
        email = req.body.email

    var x = UserService.signUp(username, password, email);
    console.log("debug")
    if (x.success) {
        ...
    }
})
```

auth.js:

```
async function signUp(username, password, email) {
     ....

     try {
         var salt = generateSalt()
         console.log("generated salt")
         var passwordHash = await hash(password, salt)
         console.log("generated hash")
     } catch (err) {
         console.error(err)
     }

     UserModel.createUser()

     return {
         success: true,
         description: 'User was created'
     }
 }



function hash(password, salt) {
    return pbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512');
}
```

user.js:

```
function createUser(username, email, salt, hash) {
    ...
    console.log("created user")
    return true
}
```

current output (wrong):

```
generated salt
debug
POST /register 200 17.164 ms - -
generated hash
created user
```

desired output:

```
generated salt
generated hash
created user
debug
POST /register 200 17.164 ms - -
```

Comment: You can `await` the returned Promise: `var x = await UserService.signUp()`, the callback would need to be made async also: `async (req, res) => {`

Comment: `UserService.signUp` is async, therefore returns a Promise and must be awaited

Comment: `my var x is undefined` --> Wrong. x is a Promise. `x.success` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not *awaiting* the function:

```
var x = UserService.signUp(username, password, email);
```

Either make the containing function `async` and `await` the result:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  //...
  var x = await UserService.signUp(username, password, email);
  //...
});
```

Or append a `.then()` to handle the result of the `Promise`:

```
UserService.signUp(username, password, email).then(x => {
  console.log("debug")
  if (x.success) {
    //...
  }
});
```